# Why are the axes switched on my pyplot histogram?

Tags: python, histogram, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data into a histogram using pyplot.hist as such:

```
hst = pp.figure()
pp.hist(spkSum)
hst.show()
```

spkSum contains the following data:`[1, 1, 9, 9, 20, 20, 33, 33, 50, 50]`

Ideally, I should have a vertical histogram whose bars sit neatly on the x-axis, reaching up to their respective values on the y-axis.  Instead, I have this:

[image: plot]

How can I fix this figure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The axes *aren't* switched.  You gave `hist` a list of numbers, five distinct numbers repeated twice, and it computed a histogram appropriately.  Maybe you're looking for a [bar plot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
spkSum = [1, 1, 9, 9, 20, 20, 33, 33, 50, 50]
pp.bar(range(len(spkSum)), spkSum)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: *facepalm* ... You are correct.  It's 3:00 AM over here, and I suppose homework is best done during the daytime.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a bar plot, but had no idea how it was called except I knew it was basically an inverted histogram.

Comment: I too didn't read the description of what module `hist` is and that `bar` exists.